# import table data from Mac .numbers file

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, import, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to crunch some numbers in:

[image: Open High Low Close Sample Data]

I have tested a few variations of importing data but failed. Really appreciate some advise. Thanks!

```
path = 'Data/Price.numbers'
with open(path) as file:    
file.readline()
for line in file:
    values = map(float, line.split())
    test.append(values)
```

Key Objectives:

1. Efficiently store the table data in a format that I can easily manipulate and apply calculations > I'm thinking of a Dict{} > Any comments?
2. Optimized for quick calculations as I need to crunch data for multiple securities > I estimate about 1,000,000 to 2,000,000 datapoint.

Answer (score 16):

The [numbers-parser](https://github.com/masaccio/numbers-parser) library can be used to parse `.numbers` files. From the example on the Github page:

```py
from numbers_parser import Document
doc = Document("my-spreasdsheet.numbers")
sheets = doc.sheets()
tables = sheets[0].tables()
rows = tables[0].rows()
```

Answer (score 3):

Open your Numbers file, go to the "File" > "export" > "To CSV" tab.

You will get your CSV file with which you can interact with Python

Enjoy

Comment: This is not particularly useful. What if there are 100, or 1000 files. This is not a programming answer.